# Advice for improving question about SOLID principles

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I wanted some advice for improving my question and I asked that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289563/what-can-i-do-for-change-the-way-i-asking-questions-on-stackoverflow?noredirect=1#comment939999_289563) and I've been told that I can ask it here. So I ask it here again.

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457026/not-exposing-iqueryable-and-not-violating-oc-principal) on Stack Overflow and it was really a problem that I faced in my work. And it got negative points and had been closed. How can I improve it, or where I can get any advice on how I can change it to be an at least normal question?

Comment: The close reason is "primarily opinion based" - and that's essentially what you do with "is it the right approach?". If you ask that, you'll get "yes", "no", "maybe", "unicorns" and anything in between and nobody will be any wiser. You'll probably already get a lot further if you edit that part of the question out and find the real question you're trying to ask.

Comment: oh that was really good advice thank you i will change that part

Comment: now i should wait for reopening?

Comment: Well to me it is still unclear what you're asking, "isn't it the violence of Open/Close principal?" doesn't really explain to me what you're after. Which specific principal, and why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: oh ok so i will make that part more cleare

Comment: i think it became much more clear

Comment: Side note: it seems like there is not a single sentence starting with upper case letter in your post. While proper spelling/grammar is not 100% required it definitely makes post less readable.